# Chrome opens PDF files only through Google Drive, other apps work fine

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, chrome-for-android, pdf

Bug: pdf files from Chrome open only in Drive app directly, disabling Drive gives me "cannot open file" error.

- I can open them from Adobe PDF app or FBreader app directly but that is annoying.
- Selecting file in File Commander also brings up app chooser correctly and respects default settings. But Chrome insists on "Drive or nothing"
- Firefox works fine too

How can I get the "choose app" dialog in Chrome and Downloads app to work?

Device: Xperia Z4 tablet, Android 6.0, chrome latest, non-rooted, updated to 32.1.A.1.185

Reinstalling drive, reinstalling chrome, reinstalling adobe pdf, resetting app defaults for all apps does not help.

Answer (score 1):

Try clearing defaults for **BOTH** of these apps. This should be in `Settings > Apps > Chrome/Google Drive.`

Comment: > resetting app defaults for all apps does not help.
I meticulously went thru all apps in Settings/Apps and re-set the defaults. No luck. Even Firefox opens PDF in adobe reader, but not Chrome.

Comment: @wizzard0 Are you rooted with a custom Rom? If so, you might be able to remove all chrome data and reflash gapps.

Comment: Not rooted, stock Sony firmware.

Comment: @wizzard0 Do you have another off viewer installed? If not that's most likely the issue.

Comment: Umm. Please read the answer text :) I have adobe pdf reader, google drive, and fbreader - 3 readers. And 2 browsers, Chrome and Firefox. I enter the URL to pdf file, Chrome opens it in Drive, FF opens in Adobe. I disable Drive, Chrome says "cant open file", FF still opens fine. Thinking about resetting the tablet...

Comment: @wizzard0 Ah, sorry. I can't think of anything right off the top of my head. I'll get back to you in the morning. (It's 2:50)

Comment: @wizzard0 Do you have an app in "Settings > Apps" called  "DocumentViewer"? If so, clear defaults for that too.